# table partitioning without recoding application?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server is it possible to perform table partition without having to recode or modify the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The application will simply see a single table, so no changes are required to your application.

[Partitioned Tables and Indexes in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(SQL.90).aspx)

[Partitioned Table and Index Strategies Using SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578580.aspx)

Comment: @khou: Your original question asks if it makes any difference: the answer is No. If you want an answer to a different question, may I suggest you ask a separate question.